# Looping over array of object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

How to loop to get all of the address ?

```
const name = {
  john: [
    {
      age: 21,
      address: 'LA',
    }
  ],
  sam: [
    {
      age: 26,
      address: 'California'
    }
  ]
}
```

I have code like this, and still get stuck how the flow is going

```
const array = Object.entries(name);
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  console.log(array[i]);
}
```

Comment: Familiarize yourself with [how to access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON](/q/11922383/4642212).

Comment: The structure is a little weird, why are age objects inside an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

If ObjectValue have multiple arrays.
Please check below code and also I have written some comments in between code.

```js
const name = { john: [ { age: 21, address: 'LA', }, { age: 23, address: 'Franch', } ], sam: [ { age: 26, address: 'California' }, { age: 24, address: 'Swiss' } ] }

var ObjectValues = Object.values(name);


// if single user have multiple data or address apply map method to ObjectValue too

var result = ObjectValues.map((ObjectValue) => {
    return ObjectValue.map(item => item.address);
});

// try to print result before combining
// console.log(result);

// combine all child arrays into single array
result = [].concat.apply([], result);

console.log(result);
```

**Using forEach loop and get all address in single array**

```js
const name = { john: [ { age: 21, address: 'LA', }, { age: 23, address: 'Franch', } ], sam: [ { age: 26, address: 'California' }, { age: 24, address: 'Swiss' } ] }

var ObjectValues = Object.values(name);
var result = [];

ObjectValues.forEach((ObjectValue) => {
  ObjectValue.map(item => result.push(item.address));
});

console.log(result);
```

**Simply write a function for best practice**

```js
const name = { john: [ { age: 21, address: 'LA', }, { age: 23, address: 'Franch', } ], sam: [ { age: 26, address: 'California' }, { age: 24, address: 'Swiss' } ] }

console.log(getAddress(name));


function getAddress(data) {
  let result = []; // initialize storage
  
  Object.values(data).forEach(ObjectValue => {
    // store address(data)
      ObjectValue.map(item => result.push(item.address));
  });
  return result; // return data
}
```

**OLD ANSWER**

`Object.entries` will return arrays of Object in [key, value] pair

So instead of using Object.entries use Object.values(it will return only "value" list of an object)

Now after extracting all value list with `Object.values`, now simply use `map` or `forEach` method to to get All address list

```js
const name = {
  john: [
    {
      age: 21,
      address: 'LA',
    }
  ],
  sam: [
    {
      age: 26,
      address: 'California'
    }
  ]
}

var ObjectValues = Object.values(name);

// map method
var result = ObjectValues.map(ObjectValue => ObjectValue[0].address);
// here I have used 0 index of an ObjectValue because ObjectValue is an array of single Object of data {age, address}

console.log(result) // check result




// forEach method
var result = []

ObjectValues.forEach(ObjectValue => result.push(ObjectValue[0].address));

console.log('With forEach method (❁´◡`❁)')
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I have a question, what if in the ObjectValue is not a single Object but multiple object with the same key, how to loop to get the all of address ?
for example:

```
const name = {
  john: [
    {
      age: 21,
      address: 'LA',
    },
 {
      age: 23,
      address: 'Franch',
    }
  ],
  sam: [
    {
      age: 26,
      address: 'California'
    },
 {
      age: 24,
      address: 'Swiss'
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can do easily. Can I update my answer?

Comment: yes of course, you can update your answer

Comment: @LendSham I have updated my answer and written three different methods. and Also read comments in code.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, `name` is acting more like a hash map as the keys are strings (e.g. `john` and `sam`) as opposed to numbers (0, 1, 2, etc.). `Object.entries()` returns key-value pairs (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)), and this is why the `array[i]` does not work.

Changing the loop slightly like below should fix things:

```
const array = Object.entries(name);

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(array)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
  // logs john: [object Object] and sam: [object Object]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick,

```
Object.values(name).map(([{address}])=>address) // ["LA", "California"]
```